What could be posible reason to increase Transaction Response time? While I am runnning Load Test again
In one of my interviews, I have been asked, Suppose you are executing a load test with 50 users. The Transaction response time was captured in 3 seconds. After some time you execute again the with same number of user seconds time response time captured 8 Secs. What could be the possible reason for increasing transaction response time?

Cache flushing. Other load. Routers down and up. Too broad. Stupid interview question.

The reason could be any: magnetic anomalies, sunspots, the system under test doing background work, 2nd test hit another node behind the load balancer, your coworker is downloading his favourite porn consuming 90% of Internet channel bandwidth, etc.
That's why looking at a single metric will never tell you the full story, you need to correlate various metrics from the load generator like:

number of concurrent users
throughput (number of transactions per second)
number of errors
response time
network throughput (incoming and outgoing traffic)

with the ones from the system under test, you should monitor at least resources consumption (CPU, RAM, Network and Disk IO, etc.) as well as application specific metrics, database slow queries and so on. In order to better analyze the impact of your load test you need to have a profiler tool or even better an APM tool installed on the system under test side, this way you will be able to get to the bottom of the bottleneck
